# Ошибка "readdirent: invalid argument" при открытии директории

Tags: golang

Требуется распарсить большой датасет из картинок структура папок следующая

```
/dataprovider
  /dataset
    /Sample001
      img001-0001.png
      img001-0002.png
      ...
    /Sample002
      img001-0001.png
      img001-0002.png
      ...
    ...
  dataprovider.go
```

Метод MapTrainingSamples предназначен для парсинга директории dataprovider/dataset

```
package dataprovider

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

type TrainingSample struct {
    Answer string
    Data   [][]float32
}

func MapTrainingSamples(callback func(TrainingSample)) {
    path := "dataprovider/dataset"
    readDir(path, func(file os.FileInfo) {
        sample := parseSample(file.Name(), filepath.Join(path, file.Name()))
        callback(sample)
    })
}

func parseSample(name, path string) TrainingSample {
    readDir(path, func(file os.FileInfo) { // тут возникает ошибка
        fmt.Println(file)
    })

    return TrainingSample{
        Answer: name,
        Data:   [][]float32{},
    }
}

func readDir(dirPath string, callback func(file os.FileInfo)) []os.FileInfo {
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(dirPath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    for _, f := range files {
        callback(f)
    }
    return files
}
```

Падает со следующей ошибкой

> $ go run main.go
>
> 2017/10/02 13:23:26 readdirent: invalid argument
>
> exit status 1

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А распечатайте `dirPath` в `readDir`. Может вы туда файлы вместо директорий суёте.

Comment: Да, вы правы, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том что в readDir прилетал файл а не папка.

```
func MapTrainingSamples(callback func(TrainingSample)) {
    path := "dataprovider/dataset"
    readDir(path, func(file os.FileInfo) {
        if file.IsDir() {
            sample := parseSample(file.Name(), filepath.Join(path, file.Name()))
            callback(sample)
        }
    })
}
```

Спасибо [Ainar-G](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/180092/ainar-g)